# Android studio does not show the screen I designed but an old screen from another project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just started using Android studio and it's really bad in my opinion. I tried to create something simple and designed a screen following youtube videos but when I run it, that looks really bad because nothing is placed where it should on the screen. Now I started a new project and created another screen inside activity_main.xml. I didn't write any code at all and it shows me an error

> error: package androidx.test.ext.junit.runners does not exist

Also it keeps showing me the screen from the first project I created not the current one and I have no idea how to continue with it. This is the main issue for now cuz I can't even see the screen I'm designing. I tried Build>Clean project and Rebuild project from the answers I read but it's still the same.

Comment: can u share the xml  code of designed screen. Used constraint layout?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for AndroidJUnit4, the gradle file should contain the following line:

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
After adding this, everything worked for me.

If it still doesn't work, make sure that you clean and/or rebuild your project. Also you can check the current version directly in Google's maven repository